# Shifting the characters in a string in Java

Tags: java, string

**Brief Explanation**

So I know this is a rather easy problem to solve but for some reason I'm confused by what it's asking me so I really just need an explanation to it more than anything.

**Problem**

Read a word from the user and display the string with the letters shifted to the right by two positions and with the letters shifted to the left by two positions in the string. Save all of the three strings in separate variables and display all three of them at the end of the program.

**Confusion**

Here's how I'm confused because I don't really understand what would shifting the letters do considering the fact that if there all being shifted the same distance in the same direction then the word you should get is the original then isn't it? I'm might be completely wrong in this. I'm also sure I've done this before but I can find the older file for it and I'm confused for some reason.

Comment: They probably want you to store the original string, the left-shifted string, and the right-shifted string (cf. "Save all of the _three_ strings"), to print them later.

Comment: I agree it's confusing. Ask whoever set the problem.

Comment: @Berger I think the issue is, if you have a word, and shift all the letters to the right ... you've basically just got the same word, but somehow all of it is further to the right. What is the transformation supposed to be?

Comment: @Berger What i'm getting from it is that after the shifts are do you print all the strings together. So what I don't know is whether or not something different is suppose to happen? or is this like the cruelest trick question ever and I'm suppose to find out that there all suppose to be the same.

Comment: @khelwood : I thought the purpose was to left shift the original string, then right shift the original string and store both versions (+ original string), but sure the only way to know is to ask the asker.

Comment: @khelwood I'm starting to think its a trick question.

Comment: @Berger But what does it mean, to left shift a whole string?

Comment: @khelwood its the letter in the string shifted left. But I think now they might have to be the same and this is an unfunny trick of a question.

Comment: Is the assignment about a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)?

Comment: @Jesper not that I know of, all the problems information is there.

Comment: i think they want something like: balls, llsba, lsbal

Comment: @goerlibe you have to consider that they all shift the same amount of a distance of two, the output wouldn't look like this given those parameters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it
Problem

Read a word from the user and display the string with the letters shifted to the right by two positions and with the letters shifted to the left by two positions in the string. Save all of the three strings in separate variables and display all three of them at the end of the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;   
public class StringShiftTwoLeftThenRight
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String word, rightShift = "", leftShift = "";

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("\nEnter a word: ");
            word = keyboard.nextLine();
            rightShift = (word.substring((0),
            (word.length()-2)));

            leftShift = (word.substring((2),(word.length())));

            System.out.println("\nThe String shifted two to right looks like this: " + rightShift);
            System.out.println("\nThe String shifted two to left looks like this: " + leftShift);
            System.out.println("\nThe String as it is looks like: " + word);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can down vote this but this was what my professor was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Shifting a set of letters can be interpreted in two ways that I know of. Lets look at an example string of '"abcdef"'. This could be left shift by two to produce the string '"cdefab"'. This the characters wrap around. The other shift would produce '"cdef"'. This is equivalent to shifting bytes where information is lost. The latter is done by deleting the first two characters, so I would guess this is not what is intended. Therefore, the intended output would be

```
Original: abcdef
Right Shifted: efabcd
Left Shifted: cdefab
```

Comment: you have to consider that they all shift the same amount of a distance of two, the output wouldn't look like this given those parameters.

Comment: @Jb01 They have all shifted a distance of two. The first two characters have to go somewhere. They either disappear or they go to the end. Because producing the same string would not be shifting at all.

Comment: yeah that why i've said to others I think this might be a trick question and that should be the outcome, from what I remember I vaguely remember that being the case in class, but I don't  know the code to produce it.

Comment: @Jb01 I do not think this is a trick question. I think you are overthinking the problem. If you are unsure of what shifting should do, then ask the teacher what the intended output is given an example input.